# How to push the row values of table into new column based on particular column?

Tags: sql-server

i have 3 columns as id,category,code here for same id i have different category and different code also, my question is how to push code into different columns based on category?

```
ex:id category code
   123  B        25
   123  B        95
   123  B        56
   123  A        81
   123  A        D7
```

i need above as like if category is A then code must go to Z1 column, if B then Z2,again we have B so code should go to column Z3, next B should go to z4 column how to achieve this? please help me.

Comment: Please phrase your question in the form of sample input and sample output after the `UPDATE`.

Comment: sounds like you want to pivot the codes into the columns but your rules aren't clear.

Comment: yeah,i should use pivot but when i used it i am getting only category A to Z1 column but not getting the category B value to Z2 and other columns

Comment: output which i need is like  for id 123 it should list 81 and D7 under Z1,25 under Z2 ,95 should be in Z3, 56 in the column Z4

Answer (score 0):

If you always want the rows to show those values and not be updated to other codes, consider computed columns. This will always show the correct code in each value:

`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mytest](
    [my:ex] [int] NULL,
    [category] [char](1) NULL,
    [code] [char](2) NULL,
    [Z1]  AS (case [CATEGORY] when 'A' then [CODE]  end),
    [Z2] AS (case [CATEGORY] when 'B' then [CODE]  end),
    [Z3] AS (case [CATEGORY] when 'C' then [CODE]  end),
    [Z4] AS (case [CATEGORY] when 'D' then [CODE]  end)
) ON [PRIMARY]`

or as a query:

`Select  [my:ex]
    , [category]
    , [code]
    , Case [CATEGORY] when 'A' then [CODE]  end as [Z1]
    , Case [CATEGORY] when 'B' then [CODE]  end as [Z2]
    , Case [CATEGORY] when 'C' then [CODE]  end as [Z3]
    , Case [CATEGORY] when 'D' then [CODE]  end as [Z4]
    from mytest`

Added for dynamic function:

`declare @sql as nvarchar(max)=N''
    declare @columns as nvarchar(500)=N''
    select  @columns = @columns + N' case [category] when ''' 
    + [category] + '''       THEN [code] END as [Z' + cast(ROW_NUMBER()
     OVER(ORDER BY [category]) as nvarchar(1)) + N'],'
    from mytest
    group by [category]
    set @columns = left(@columns, len(@columns)-1)
    set @sql = 'select [my:ex], [category], [code], ' + @columns + ' FROM 
    mytest'
    exec(@sql)`

Following last comment. Adds additional column for each category/code combination:

`declare @sql as nvarchar(max)=N''
    declare @columns as nvarchar(max)=N''
    declare @rcount as int=1
    select  @columns = @columns + N' case [category]+[code] when ''' 
    + [category] + [code] + ''' THEN [code] END as [Z' + cast(count([category] +               [code]) OVER(ORDER BY [category] + [code] ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as  nvarchar(5)) + N'],'
    from mytest
    group by [category],[code]
    set @columns = left(@columns, len(@columns)-1)
    print @columns
    set @sql = 'select [my:ex], [category], [code], ' + @columns + ' FROM 
    mytest'
    exec(@sql)`

Comment: Thank you for the above query,it is helpful and in my table i have multiple A and B categories as i had explained, based on that is it possible to categorize using pivot?

Comment: I've made it dynamic to pivot the results.

Comment: Great thing and its looks like case statement and dividing code into only Z1 and Z2,my doubt is if category is A then Z1(if multiple also) and for first B category  code should go to Z2,second B category code should go to Z3 so on..is this possible?

Comment: Thank you so much,its exactly what i wanted.

Comment: It was a pleasure. Especially if you credit my answer ;-)